# Tomcat выбрасывает NullPointerException при попытке создать Cookie

Tags: java, cookie, tomcat

В общем проблема в том, что проект, созданный на ПК(где он работал) был перенесён на ноут, где томкат начал выписывать фортеля такого плана:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.apache.tomcat.util.http.LegacyCookieProcessor.generateHeader(LegacyCookieProcessor.java:295)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.generateCookieString(Response.java:959)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.addCookie(Response.java:907)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.addCookie(ResponseFacade.java:392)
 controller.ControllerServlet.service(ControllerServlet.java:49)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 controller.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:62)
 controller.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:34)
```

строка:  `ControllerServlet.java:49` является добавлением кук в респонс:

```
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

а строки кода в фильтрах банально яв-ся выполнением самих фильтров:

```
chain.doFilter(req, resp);
```

Никогда не сталкивался  с таким, по гуглу советовали обновить сам томкат, до этого стоял 8.0.28, попробовал 8.0.30 - то же самое.Может есть вариант, где принудительно в томкате можно включить этот куки процессор?

Только вот проект крутится на intellijdidea 5 ultimate и там в томкате весьма мало настроек, а проект завтра показывать =(

Answer (score 1):

В общем суть пустых кук изначальных, нно, при методе таком например:

```
>  public Cookie getCookie(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
        if (cookies != null) {
            for (Cookie c : cookies) {
                if (c.getName().equals("locale")) {
                    logger.info("Cookie was retrieved " + c.getValue());
                    return c;
                }
            }
        }
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("locale", "en");
        cookie.setMaxAge(MAX_AGE_COOKIE);
        cookie.setPath(req.getContextPath());
        logger.info("Cookie was created " + cookie.getValue());
        resp.addCookie(cookie);
        return cookie;
    }
```

посоветовали сделать доп. обёртку на request и response, чтобы request не был null, ситуация вышла странноватая, т.к. по сути метод должен был при нулевой куке создавать новые, и нулл приходил можно сказать сюда:

> Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();

что допустимо, в общем, если кто ещё столкнётся с такой проблемой совет - проверить сам request на null и в довесок сделать класс обёртку для проверки, т.к. я новичок, частенько на подводные камни натыкаюсь, но что надо понимать - лучше перепроверить, чем недопроверить.